# @SpringBootApplication annotation effects in JUnit Tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-boot-test

I have a spring boot non-web application.

I have added some integration tests for my applications which work well.

My main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and my integration test class is annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest`.

If I change my main class annotation to `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`
and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to be more explicit, my test class give a compile time error saying it cannot detect one of the classes being used and forces me to add more information.

So I have to change the annotations as below `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest(classes = EligibilityJobRunner.class)`.

I've read that `@SpringBootApplication` is an convenience annotation for the above three mentioned annotations then why this difference? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@SpringBootApplication` is a meta annotation that applies more annotations than the ones you have it replaced with:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
public @interface SpringBootApplication {
```

If you don't want to use `@SpringBootApplication`, try annotating your class with all of the following annotations:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
```

In your case, `@SpringBootConfiguration` is missing.

Next time you run your test, put debugging breakpoints at various points in [SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java) to see what is going on behind the scene.

But I think these lines show where the problem is:

```
    Class<?> found = new SpringBootConfigurationFinder()
            .findFromClass(mergedConfig.getTestClass());
    Assert.state(found != null,
            "Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use "
                    + "@ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) "
                    + "with your test");
```

Comment: Seems to be working at runtime if I add @ SpringBootConfiguration instead of plain @Configuration. But Intellij still shows me the compile time error for some reason.

Comment: There's an open ticket on IntelliJ's bug tracker for better integration with Spring Boot and it is still in porgress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139669. I suggest you mention this issue there too.